# Android Service shuts down while Runnable is still executing

Tags: android, multithreading, service, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a Service in my app with which I send requests to a server. After I send a request to start an operation on the server, I need to poll the server for updates by sending a request every 15 seconds to track the progress. For this I use a ScheduledExecutorService that calls a Runnable.

The Service does a bunch of things in `onHandleIntent` and then starts the ScheduledExecutorService that does the polling. All of this is working fine.

**The issue is while the ScheduledExecutorService is executing the Runnable at intervals, the service gets destroyed, as in the onDestroy method is called. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?**

I have a Broadcast Receiver registered in the service that can be triggered any time by the user while the ScheduledExecutorService is executing the Runnable. **But since the Service is destroyed, the Receiver gets unregistered.**

Here is some simplified code:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnHandleIntent started");

    try {

        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (getActionUpload().equals(action)) {

                wakeLock.acquire();
                notificationConfig = new CustomNotificationConfig();

                //Register receiver to stop operation
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ThirdPartyStopReceiver.ACTION_STOP);
                filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                mThirdPartyStopReceiver = new ThirdPartyStopReceiver();
                registerReceiver(mThirdPartyStopReceiver, filter);

                Boolean operationStarted = startOperation();

                if (operationStarted) {
                    checkProgressAtIntervals();
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error with XML");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        wakeLock.release();
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    try {
        //Unregister the receiver
        unregisterReceiver(mThirdPartyStopReceiver);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        //Receiver has already been unregistered. Do nothing
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void checkProgressAtIntervals() {
    Log.d(TAG,"in checkProgressAtIntervals");

    final ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int progress = sendProgressRequest();

                if(isCanceled){
                    sendCancelRequest();
                    ses.shutdown(); //Stop polling
                }

                if (progress >= 100) {
                    ses.shutdown(); //Stop polling
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception in sendProgressRequest ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, 1, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

public class ThirdPartyStopReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ACTION_STOP = "thirdpartystop";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Cancel request received in onReceive");
        isCanceled = true;

        //...

    }
}
```

So as you can see, I need to execute some code in the service if a "Stop" broadcast is received.

I have tried using a Handler with its `postDelayed` method but the service gets destroyed before the Handler starts to execute so the Runnable never executes. I tried instantiating the Handler with `Looper.myLooper()` but with the same result. 
Since the runnable contains HTTP calls, instantiating Handler with `Looper.getMainLooper()` throws a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: You could use a foreground service here is a help link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using an `IntentService`, which stops after it ends its work, that is, the `onHandleIntent` method. An `IntentService` is intended to be short-lived.

Try using a regular `Service` instead. Mind that Android can stop a Service at its own discretion, but in a general manner the Service will run for a long period.

Comment: This worked! I moved the code from `onHandleIntent` to `onStart` and changed my class to extend `Service`, instead of `IntentService`.